# Merge wavefront obj tool

Tags: wavefront

I want to merge two obj files into a single one from the command line.

I tried to append them to each other but the result is incorrect (some void is incorrectly filled)

Is it possible to do it in an automated way, and is there a tool to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tools that seems to do the job:

http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/proj/trimesh2/

```
$mesh_cat iron.obj maiden.obj -o ironmaiden.obj
```